# Why do I see this when installing pkgs "/usr/bin/mandb: can't search directory /usr/local/share/man: Permission denied"

Tags: permissions

With this installation:
aptitude install qttools5-dev libqt5svg5-dev qt5-image-formats-plugins libexiv2-dev libraw-dev

And the last several this week I see this message when its done:
[...]

```
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
/usr/bin/mandb: can't search directory /usr/local/share/man: Permission denied
/usr/bin/mandb: can't search directory /usr/local/share/man: Permission denied
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu3) ...
[...]
```

Just started happening this week but there has been so much activity I cannot recount exactly the process or times.

Googling I find hits on the string in my subject line but all quite old.  Only 1 was relatively new  at 2020 but not helpful  Seems there were bugs with this back in 2013, 9 yrs seems a bit long to be hitting the same problem.

Perhaps my permissions in that are are wrong:

```
ls -ald /usr/local
drwxr-xr-x 16 reader nfsu 20 May 21 00:50 /usr/local

reader:nfsu are my uid and group

ls -ald /usr/local/man
lrwxrwxrwx 1 reader nfsu 14 May 21 00:50 /usr/local/man -> /usr/share/man
```

I ran sudo chown -R root:root /usr/local but it changed nothing.

What should my permissions look like?  Should /usr/local/man be a symlink to
/usr/share/man?

Comment: Most probably `/usr/local` is a mountpoint (nfs, sdcard, ...) and the mount options deny access. Try to remove `/usr/local/man` from `/etc/manpath.config`. Which only solve the mandb problem, but not the permission denied problem.

Comment: It is a zfs mountpoint.  I has been for at least 2 yrs or so on several version upgrades of ubuntu.  Is that likely to be the source of this problem all of a sudden this week?

Comment: It is a mount point for zfs fs, but always has been for about 2 yrs over several ubuntu versions.  Is it still likely to be the problem? Can you show me permissions of /usr/local/share/man on a host you have access to?  OOPS sorry I thought my other comment had been rejected... not that familiar with how this forum works.